# How create BASE URL of website if the menu are in different folder?

Tags: php, html, base-url

I know it is stupid to do but I have the situation that I create menus in different folders. And I tried to create the baseurl for menu.

```
function getBaseUrl() 
{
     $currentPath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($currentPath);
    $hostName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
    $protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https://'?'https://':'http://';
    return $protocol.$hostName.$pathInfo['dirname']."/";
}
```

Use base url like `<?php echo getBaseUrl(); ?>`. My problem is:

Let I have menus ***aaa bbb ccc ddd***. And page of `aaa` menu is inside `folder1/page1.php`

page of `bbb` menu is inside `folder2/page2.php`. I can't go from `aaa` menu to `bbb` menu.

Any one have Idea? please suggest

Comment: Where are you calling this function `getBaseUrl`? Can you post the menus HTML?

Comment: @KAD I use getBaseUrl() in navigation page and include in all pages. Menu pages are simple. No so complected. I just want to get proper hyper link  for all menus

Comment: `| <a href="<?php echo getBaseUrl();?>hims/operate_exp.php" <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'operate_exp.php'){ echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Operating Expences</a> 
 | <a href="<?php echo getBaseUrl();?>hims/proposed/revenue.php" <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'revenue.php'){ echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Revenue</a>
` Operating Expences is in main folder (hims) and Revenue is inside hims/proposed folder

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array with the list of pages you have indexed by a label:

```
function getBaseUrl($naviItem) 
{
    var $navigation = array( 
       'aaa_menu' => '/folder1/page1.php', 
       'bbb_menu' => '/folder2/page2.php'
    );

    //$currentPath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    //$pathInfo = pathinfo($currentPath);
    $hostName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
    $protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https://'?'https://':'http://';

    // return the path relative to the passed navitem
    return $protocol.$hostName.$navigation[$naviItem];
}
```

Then in your HTML, you pass this label relative to the navigation item you want to achieve the baseURL for :

```
<a href="<?php echo getBaseUrl('aaa_menu'); ?>">aaa</a>
<a href="<?php echo getBaseUrl('bbb_menu'); ?>">bbb</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Shrestha it's very easy just define constant and use

```
define('DOMAIN_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/projectname/');
```

And when setting the links -

```
<a href="<?php echo DOMAIN_URL; ?>/folder1/page1.php">aaa</a> 
<a href="<?php echo DOMAIN_URL ?>/folder2/page2.php">bbb</a>
```

Comment: ok, thnks but I have header page which contain css and js file. It could be use for both menu. I can't use 2 different links. How to do that?

Comment: Where do I should placed the define? On contruct at controller? Or where?